# Record save video from webcam in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Hi how i can make a Windows App with some third party dll to make a webcam video recorder.
I want to make a personal video log App so suggest any DLL.Help

Comment: Seriously. Google is still alive... http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Webcam+C%23

Comment: No, you can't do this, because there's no such thing as "C# .NET".

Comment: loxxy, Google is what brought me here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [DirectShow API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture webcame video. You can use the DirectShow.Net library to more easily access its functionality in .NET

For example:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markhsch/archive/2007/11/19/c-webcam-user-control-source.aspx

Another option would be to use the [Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368.aspx) API. Channel 9 contains an older article (from 2008) where Scott Hanselman shows you how to capture pictures with a webcam:

- http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Look-at-me-Windows-Image-Acquisition

Capturing video using WIA (instead of images):

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WebCamService.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wiascriptingdotnet.aspx

However, you might not want to use it anymore as WIA 2.0 (released with Vista) is mainly targeted toward scanners instead of other imaging devices such as webcams. It still contains legacy support for WIA 1.0 applications though.

Comment: I used WIA 1.0 for static images from a webcam in a .Net project and it worked. It was not so hard, don't know how it works with video.

Comment: Possible, with some tweaking. For example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WebCamService.aspx

Comment: But isn't DirectShow.NET just interfaces? How can it be used to access DirectShow's functionality?